# Calculate mean of vector primitive numerical values generically

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to write a generic `mean` function for all values within an Vector of generic numerical primitive type.

Could the following implementation be possible more efficient, yet still generic enough for all the possible numerical primitives?

Is the `num` crate really needed?

```rust
extern crate num;
use std::iter::Sum;
use std::ops::Div;

fn mean<'a, T, U>(values: &'a [T]) -> U::Output
    where T: Sum<&'a T> + num::ToPrimitive,
          U: num::NumCast + Div
{
    U::from(values.iter().sum::<T>()).unwrap() / U::from(values.len()).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let arr_i32: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 5];
    let arr_f32: Vec<f32> = vec![1.1, 2.2, 5.5];
    println!("Mean of ({:?}) is: {}", arr_i32, mean::<_, f32>(&arr_i32));
    println!("Mean of ({:?}) is: {}", arr_f32, mean::<_, f32>(&arr_f32));
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is not efficient ?

Comment: I didn't say I think that, I was just asking, if this code could be written more efficiently. For example, I think that the wrapping `U` into `Option<U>` and then calling the`unwrap()` method is unnecessary, because `iter::sum` has always a value and `&[].len()` has it too.